# Why is the map method (with division) returning NaN?

Tags: javascript

The first function (codeScript) is used to "encrypt a number". The second (descrypter) is for "decrypting", as the name suggests:

```js
const num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const num2 = [4, 3, 2, 1];

const codeScript = (code1, code2, mult) => {

  console.log(code1)

  const map1 = code1.map(x => x * mult)
  code1 = []
  code1.push(map1)

  console.log(code1)

  console.log(code2)

  const map2 = code2.map(x => x * mult)
  code2 = []
  code2.push(map2)

  console.log(code2)

  descrypter(code1, code2, mult)
}

descrypter = (code1, code2, mult) => {

  const map3 = code1.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code1 = []
  code1.push(map3)

  console.log(code1)

  const map4 = code2.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code2 = []
  code2.push(map4)

  console.log(code2)
};

codeScript(num1, num2, 2);
```

However, the second function is returning me the NaN when dividing the items in the num1 and num2 array (code1, code2) by the "mult".

```
descrypter = (code1, code2, mult) => {

  const map3 = code1.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code1 = []
  code1.push(map3)

  console.log(code1)

  const map4 = code2.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code2 = []
  code2.push(map4)

  console.log(code2)
};
```

I thought the error was in the way it was performing the map, but now I don't know.

Comment: Add console.logs after the `.push()` calls in your encoding routine so you can see what `code1` and `code2` look like.

Comment: @Pointy There are already enough `console.log()`s (including those for `code1` and `code2`) in the code.

Comment: you're trying to divide a list by a num

Comment: @Andreas yea, I guess I need some coffee.

Comment: what do you expect should be in code1 and code2 after encrypter?

Comment: @depperm Hmm, but I used the same map system multiplying the list by a number and it worked. Why doesn't it work with division? Do you have any suggestions on how I could make it work?

Comment: you are working with a list of lists instead of a list of numbers. you do `code1.push(map1)` (map1 being a list), instead of `concat` or an extend

Comment: @depperm After encrypting, I expect every number in it to be multiplied by two. That is: 1234 = 2468 and 4321 = 8642. In the second function I try to do the reverse, however it is in it that gives me the error.

Comment: if you add `console.log({item, mult})` above `return item / mult;` you'll see that `item` is an array, not a number.

Comment: It worked, you were right about the lists. It would never work the way I was doing it. Thank you @depperm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are adding a new list to a list (`code1.push(map2)`), making a list of lists. Instead you could either set `code1 = map1` or use `map1` as parameter to pass to `descrypter`

```js
const num1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const num2 = [4, 3, 2, 1];

const codeScript = (code1, code2, mult) => {

  console.log(code1)

  const map1 = code1.map(x => x * mult)
  code1 = map1

  console.log(code1)

  console.log(code2)

  const map2 = code2.map(x => x * mult)
  code2 = map2

  console.log(code2)

  descrypter(code1, code2, mult)
}

descrypter = (code1, code2, mult) => {

  const map3 = code1.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code1 = map3

  console.log(code1)

  const map4 = code2.map(function(item) {
    return item / mult;
  });
  code2 = map4

  console.log(code2)
};

codeScript(num1, num2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
  const map2 = code2.map(x => x * mult)
  code1 = []
  code1.push(map2)
```

You're creating an array containing the "encrypted" array. You should change this to:

```
  const map1 = code1.map(x => x * mult)
  code1 = map1
```

in order to have an array of numbers. You should to the same with the rest of the "encryption" and "decryption" code.